# android how to use intent to give back data to mainActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have DialogSheet Acivity its like form i want to send the data to MainActivity how tried alot but never work

save the button take all the information form the user then save it but i dont know how to send it to main

```
Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // take all the information form the user then save it to the card
            // i used getActivity instead of MyclassName.this bcs it did not work
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
                String Sname =Name.getText().toString();
                String Sweight = Weight.getText().toString();
                String Sdate = SelectDate.getText().toString();

               // intent send to MainActivity 
                intent.putExtra("ExtraName",Sname);
                intent.putExtra("ExtraWeight",Sweight);
                intent.putExtra("ExtraDate",Sdate);

                // it did not work i dont know why 
                MainActivity.logArrayList.add(new Log(Sname,Sweight,Sdate));
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

How i used intent in MainActivity i tried to but insert() in the DialogSheet Acivity but its only crach please help me

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
           Intent intent = getIntent();
           String  Bname = intent.getStringExtra("ExtraName");
           String  Bweight = intent.getStringExtra("ExtraWeight");
           String  Bdate = intent.getStringExtra("ExtraDate");

  }
    public void insert(){
         logArrayList.add(new Log(Bname,Bweight,Bdate));
         LogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);

Comment: @koding thanks  but i need to add this to my list see insert()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `DialogSheet` from `MainActivity` you may can do this:

add a method to your `MainActivity` like this:

```
void addCard(String name, String weight, String date){
  // here add item to list
}
```

and change your click listener code at `DialogSheet` to this:

```
Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // take all the information form the user then save it to the card
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addCard(
                                            Name.getText().toString(),
                                            Weight.getText().toString(),
                                            SelectDate.getText().toString()
                                            );
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundle to recover data.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
           Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
           String  Bname = b.getStringExtra("ExtraName");
           String  Bweight = b.getStringExtra("ExtraWeight");
           String  Bdate = b.getStringExtra("ExtraDate");

    }
```

Comment: i think this is not the problem , bcs i want to add the varublase to my list by  insert() but the problem how to make it work when i click on Save